# How can you use tkinter widgets across files in python?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, widget, structure

I am relatively new to programming and I noticed that coding everything in 2 files (settings and main) gets very messy as your code grows.
However, when I split my code into many files, I run into issues where I cannot import fileB.py intro FileA.py and use variables or widgets from file A inside my file B (I get undefined names error).

I am using tkinter for the UI, so my main file is the tk loop (main.py). Each button refers to functions in different files. It works well, until my function includes button states or entry text.

This example is with tkinter but I run into this problem on many occasions, because of my code structure I believe.

## File A (main.py)

```
import FileB
import tkinter
from tkinter import Checkbutton, Tk, Entry, BooleanVar

root = Tk() # initialize blank window
root.geometry("500x500")

# text entry
E1 = Entry(root, bd=5, width = 8)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Checkbox
CB_var = BooleanVar()
CB = Checkbutton(root, text="Get text", variable=CB_var, command=FileB.get_text() )
CB.grid(row=0, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

## FileB (FileB.py)

```
def get_text():
    if CB.var == True:
         entry_text = E1.get()
         E1.config(state=DISABLED)
         print(entry_text)
         E1.delete(0, END)
    elif CB.var == False:
         E1.config(state=NORMAL)
         print("Checkbox not selected")
```

Since E1 is defined before my function is called, I would expect my function to be able to change the state of E1, get its text and empty the text; as if the function was in my main.py.

The actual output is undefined name error since E1 is not a variable in my FileB.

Answer (score 0):

As `FileB` is imported by `main.py`, `FileB` cannot access objects in `main.py`.  You need to pass the objects in `main.py` via function parameters.

Suggest to put your widgets into a class and pass the instance of the class to `FileB.get_text()` function.

**File A (main.py)**

```
from tkinter import Checkbutton, Tk, Entry, BooleanVar
import FileB

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        # text entry
        self.E1 = Entry(root, bd=5, width = 8)
        self.E1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        # Checkbox
        self.CB_var = BooleanVar()
        self.CB = Checkbutton(root, text="Get text", variable=self.CB_var, command=lambda: FileB.get_text(self))
        self.CB.grid(row=0, column=2)

root = Tk() # initialize blank window
root.geometry("500x500")
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**File B (FileB.py)**

```
from tkinter import DISABLED, NORMAL, END

def get_text(gui):
    if gui.CB_var.get() == True:
         entry_text = gui.E1.get()
         gui.E1.config(state=DISABLED)
         print(entry_text)
         gui.E1.delete(0, END)
    else:
         gui.E1.config(state=NORMAL)
         print("Checkbox not selected")
```

Comment: YES, class inheritence is the exact concept I was missing! Thank you very much it works super well.